How to highlight the boarder of the current page using react-pdf-viewer?
When I scroll through the PDF, I use the onPageChange plugin to help me know the page number I'm currently at. I want to highlight the borders of the page with the current page number in the PDF viewer. How can I do that?

Use the onPageChange event handler to update the state with the current page number:
const handlePageChange = (page: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
};

Render the Viewer component with the PDF file and define a custom PageLayer to highlight the border of the current page:
const Example = () => {
    const { pdfDocument } = usePdf({
        file: 'path/to/your/pdf.pdf',
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Viewer
                fileUrl="path/to/your/pdf.pdf"
                plugins={[
                    {
                        onPageChange: handlePageChange,
                    },
                ]}
            />
            <div className="highlight-border" style={{ border: '2px solid red' }}>
                Page {currentPage + 1}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

